# navigation bar items not being removed when view disappears

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a uisegementcontrol and a uibarbutton that gets added to the navigation bar of the navigation controller. When I push to the next view, however, I want them to be removed. I tried several approaches, but nothing seems to be removing them. One approach was using viewWillDisappear and having the segementcontrol and the bar button removedFromSuperView. Another was to call the removeFromSuperView from the method that pushes to the next scene. Nothing seems to be working. I've actually been stuck on this for a really long time!

Also, the view controller "X" that has the segement control and the bar button is presented through a presentViewController. X then pushes the other view controller.

Here is the code for the segement control

```
NSArray *headers = @[@"Tracks", @"Playlists"];
self.savedMusic = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:headers];
CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
CGRect segFrame = CGRectMake(80, 5, size.width - 140, 35);
self.savedMusic.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.savedMusic.frame = segFrame;
self.savedMusic.tag =1;

[self.savedMusic setTitle:@"Tracks"
        forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[self.savedMusic setTitle:@"Playlists"
        forSegmentAtIndex:1];

[self.savedMusic addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(whatToDisplay)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.savedMusic.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.savedMusic];
```

Here is the code for the viewWillDisapear

```
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
[self.savedMusic removeFromSuperview];
```

And here is the code for the method that switches to the new view

```
       PlaylistTracksTableViewController *vc = [[PlaylistTracksTableViewController alloc] init];

    [self.savedMusic removeFromSuperview];
    [[self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what you are doing is not how you manipulate the contents of the navigation bar. Do not talk to `self.navigationController.navigationBar`. Instead, each view controller should set its own `self.navigationItem`, and the runtime will use that to populate the navigation bar for that view controller.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do this for a uisegementcontrol?

Comment: `self.navigationItem.titleView = mySegmentedControl` — However, although that works fine and is perfectly legal, you should also be asking yourself why a segmented control needs to be in the navigation bar. Why not at the top of the view controller's view?

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion. I just made the change to the titleview and its still having the same issue, so I'm going to add it to the top of the view like you suggested. I personally thought that it looked cool on the nav bar, but it doesn't seem to want to work

Comment: strange - i just noticed that the left bar button is also not being removed when the view changes

Comment: Do not try to change `self.navigationController.navigationBar`, and do not try to change `self.navigationItem` dynamically. Just set up `self.navigationItem` _once_ in each view controller and leave it alone after that. The runtime will then swap items in and out of the navigation bar for you as view controllers are pushed and popped.